# Swipe Function- Universal Device Compatibility issue during automation testing using appium

Tags: android, maven, automation, swipe, appium

How should one use **swipe/scroll** for **maven automation testing** using **appium**  so that it is **compatible** for all the devices? I tried using fixed coordinates and then converting them into percentages of the screen height and width, so that the corresponding coordinates are used for swipe in some other device, but i think because of the 5th parameter of the swipe function (swipe duration), it is not getting universal. What is the work around to achieve universal compatibility for swipe?